# Visual Studio C++ Matrix

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, matrix

I have to write an algorithm for a matrix . All I have to do is to order matrix by main diagonal , with permutations of lines and cols. I write this code, but I forget something and I don't know what... Can you help me ?

```
    #include "stdafx.h"

int i, j, n, a[100][100], k, aux;
void muta(int x, int y) {
    for (int k = 0;k < n;k++) {
        aux = a[k][x];
        a[k][x] = a[k][y];
        a[k][y] = aux;
    }
    aux = a[0][x];
    for (int k = 0;k < n-1;k++) {
        a[k][x] = a[k+1][x];
    }
    a[n - 1][x] = aux;
    aux = a[n - 1][y];
    for (int t = n-1;t >=1;t--) {
        a[t][y] = a[t-1][y];
    }
    a[0][y] = aux;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Nr. of lines and cols: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0;i < n;i++) {
        for (j = 0;j < n;j++) {
            printf("a[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
            scanf_s("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0;i < n;i++) {
        for (j = 0;j < n;j++) {
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0;i < n - 1;i++) {
        for (j = i + 1;j < n;j++) {
            if (a[i][i] < a[j][j]){
                muta(i, j);
            }
            for (int k = 0;k < n;k++) {
                for (int t = 0;t < n;t++) {
                    printf("%d ", a[k][t]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    for (i = 0;i < n;i++) {
        for (j = 0;j < n;j++) {
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

For example: If I write 3 (lines and cols) then elements like this

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Program must return :

```
9 8 7
6 5 4
3 2 1
```

Elements from main diagonale must be order by desc. Any idea ?

Comment: We need example input, expected output, and actual output. You gave us the first two. Please show us actual output.

Comment: @Dialecticus, sorry for delay. Here's what i got: `6 5 4 9 8 7 3 2 1`